# Tough workouts directly after waking up

Tags: training, bicycling, timing

I set up a new training plan for me and the only time during the day I have enough space for cycling training (with two children and a full time job) is directly after getting up. So I get up at 5am, 15 min. for my smoothie and go.

Is it ok to do tough workouts right after waking up? I am talking about something like 90 over-under (ftp) cycling training. I do workouts during the week on Mondays, Wednesdays and Thursdays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first warning flag there is

> I set up a new training plan for me

but I won't go into that.

The time limitation I totally understand, and is there anything wrong with a tough workout first thing in the morning? No. Is it optimal? Probably not.

I'll admit, I don't cycle, so I don't know how relevant this is (it comes from early morning weight training sessions), but I would consider forgoing the smoothie before the session and instead go for something like an espresso.

Reason is, when you put food in your stomach, the body pulls blood into the internal organs (intestines and such like) for digestion. If you're stressing the body with physical exercise directly after eating something (a smoothie counts as eating), then you're telling your body to pull the blood supply into the muscles. Your body isn't smart enough to understand that exercise isn't a life threatening event, so there's every chance it'll try and get rid of the digestion blood requirement in favour of supplying blood to the muscles for fuel. This is why some people throw up during intense exercise (and also why eating directly after a seriously tough session might not be a great idea).

That is mainly through personal experience though, so you may find that you can stomach it (unintended pun) without any issues.